# JS split with db data

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, split

I am wondering how would be the best way to do the following:

I am returning my database data via ajax using **|** as a delimiter between the data.

```
success: function (data, responseText, textStatus) {
    var dataBack = data.split("|");

    $('#name').html(dataBack[0]);
    $('#company').html(dataBack[1]);
    $('#address').html(dataBack[2]);
    $('#phone').html(dataBack[3]);
    $('#email').html(dataBack[4]);
    $('#city').html(dataBack[5]);
    $('#state').html(dataBack[6]);
    $('#zip').html(dataBack[7]);
    $('#accNum').html(dataBack[8]);

    howManyCases = dataBack[9];
    var htmlCode = '';
    var caseStats = '';
    var myDate = new Date(dataBack[10]);                
    var month = new Array();

    month[0]="01";month[1]="02";month[2]="03";month[3]="04";month[4]="05";month[5]="06";
    month[6]="07";month[7]="08";month[8]="09";month[9]="10";month[10]="11";month[11]="12";

    var theFinalDate = myDate.getFullYear() + '-' + month[myDate.getMonth()] + '-' + myDate.getDate();

    if (dataBack[14] == 0) {
        caseStats = 'PENDING';
    } else {
        caseStats = 'ACCEPTED';
    }

    htmlCode = '<td width="124" style="padding-top: 8px; padding-left: 10px;" id="caseDate">' + theFinalDate + '</td>' + 
                '<td width="160" style="padding-top: 8px;" id="caseNum">' + dataBack[11] + '</td>' + 
                '<td width="172" style="padding-top: 8px;" id="caseLab">' + dataBack[12] + '</td>' + 
                '<td width="87" style="padding-top: 8px; color: #d8a401;" id="caseStatus">' + caseStats + '</td>' + 
                '<td width="59" style="padding-top: 8px;" id="caseQue">' + dataBack[13] + '</td>';

    $('#cases').html(htmlCode);
```

**dataBack[9]** stores how many records are returned (0-4) "limit 5"

**dataBack[10]-[14]** is the data needed to populate what i need for each table row.

Likewise, if there are more than **1 record returned** then that number would continue **dataBack[15]-[19]**, etc etc.

So what would be best the to do this in some type of loop?

Comment: You should have a look at json which is usually used to exchange such data.

Comment: Agreed, JSON would make your life much easier here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of some possibilities, it uses looping to make code more reuseable, of course you will need to mould these ideas into something that you actually want as I can not guess exactly from your example as you seem to be mixing the displayed data.

**CSS**

```
.caseDate {
    width: 124px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.caseNum {
    width: 160px;
    padding-top: 8px;
}
.caseLab {
    width: 172px;
    padding-top: 8px;
}
.caseStatus {
    width: 87px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    color: #d8a401;
}
.caseQue {
    width: 59px;
    padding-top: 8px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var howManyCases,
    table = document.createElement("table"),
    tbody = document.createElement("tbody"),
    data = "John Smith|Some Company|The Street|000 - 000 000|john@some.company|Lost|Sunny|123-456|0123456789|3|" + Date.now() + "|1001010010|LAB1234|Que1234|0|John Smith|Some Company|The Street|000 - 000 000|john@some.company|Lost|Sunny|123-456|0123456789|3|" + Date.now() + "|1001010010|LAB1234|Que1234|0|John Smith|Some Company|The Street|000 - 000 000|john@some.company|Lost|Sunny|123-456|0123456789|3|" + Date.now() + "|1001010010|LAB1234|Que1234|0|John Smith|Some Company|The Street|000 - 000 000|john@some.company|Lost|Sunny|123-456|0123456789|3|" + Date.now() + "|1001010010|LAB1234|Que1234|0|John Smith|Some Company|The Street|000 - 000 000|john@some.company|Lost|Sunny|123-456|0123456789|3|" + Date.now() + "|1001010010|LAB1234|Que1234|0|John Smith|Some Company|The Street|000 - 000 000|john@some.company|Lost|Sunny|123-456|0123456789|3|" + Date.now() + "|1001010010|LAB1234|Que1234|0",
    month = [],
    i;

for (i = 1; i < 13; i += 1) {
    if (i < 10) {
        month.push("0" + i);
    } else {
        month.push(i.toString());
    }
}

tbody.id = "cases";
table.appendChild(tbody);
document.body.appendChild(table);

function success(data) {
    var dataBack = data.split("|"),
        length = dataBack.length,
        fields = ['name', 'company', 'address', 'phone', 'email', 'city', 'state', 'zip', 'accNum'],
        caseStats = '',
        classes,
        myDate,
        theFinalDate,
        i,
        tr,
        tempTd,
        records = [];

    for (i = 0; i < length; i += 15) {
        records.push(dataBack.slice(0, 15));
    }

    records.forEach(function (record, recordNum) {
        fields.forEach(function (field, index) {
            var newDiv = document.createElement("div");

            newDiv.id = field + recordNum;
            newDiv.textContent = record[index];
            document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
        });

        howManyCases = parseInt(record[9], 10);
        myDate = new Date(parseInt(record[10], 10));
        theFinalDate = myDate.getFullYear() + '-' + month[myDate.getMonth()] + '-' + myDate.getDate();

        if (parseInt(record[14], 10) === 0) {
            caseStats = 'PENDING';
        } else {
            caseStats = 'ACCEPTED';
        }

        classes = {
            "caseDate": theFinalDate,
            "caseNum": record[11],
            "caseLab": record[12],
            "caseStatus": caseStats,
            "caseQue": record[13]
        };

        tr = document.createElement("tr");
        Object.keys(classes).forEach(function (className) {
            tempTd = document.createElement("td");
            tempTd.className = className;
            tempTd.textContent = classes[className];
            tr.appendChild(tempTd);
        });

        tbody.appendChild(tr);
    });
}

success(data);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/xnD43/)